# необходимо создать прозрачное окно или область для вывода информации

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net

Имеется игра, которая запущена в оконном режиме на весь экран, по верх нее можно выводить какую то информацию, как это делают некоторые программы.
Хотелось бы создать подобную область и прозрачную и чтобы нажатия мыши не на этом окне останавливались а проходили насквозь в игру, другими словами растянуть форму на всю ширину и сделать ей topmost не прокатит, ибо на игре невозможно будет кликать мышой.
Подскажите как реализовать подобное окно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Windows Forms 2.0 there is a new property called ShowWithoutActivation – which you would need to override on the Form.
>   In native applications you can use SetWindowPos with the
>   SWP_NOACTIVATE flag or the ShowWindow with the SW_SHOWNA flag.

Взято отсюда(по линке больше информации):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423234/make-a-form-not-focusable-in-c-sharp